# Performance of Vectorized vs Devectorized vs Multithreaded Julia codes

Tags: multithreading, performance, julia, benchmarking

I have a large array of floating point numbers. I am multiplying the array by a scalar. What is the best(fastest) way to do it in Julia?

```
using BenchmarkTools    

global const dim1 = 2000
global const dim2 = 2000
global const α = 0.9
global const α_array = α.*eye(dim2, dim2)

function decay1(x)
    x .*= α
end

function decay2(x)
    for j in 1:dim2
        for i in 1:dim1
            @inbounds x[i,j] *= α
        end
    end
end

function decay3(x)
    Threads.@threads for j in 1:dim2
        for i in 1:dim1
            @inbounds x[i, j] *= α
        end
    end
end

function decay4(x)
    x *= α_array
end

function decay5(x)
    scale!(x, α)
end

x = ones(dim1, dim2)
print("\nVectorized:\n")
@btime decay1(x)

x = ones(dim1, dim2)
print("\nDevectorized:\n")
@btime decay2(x)

x = ones(dim1, dim2)
print("\nMultithreaded:\n")
@btime decay3(x)

x = ones(dim1, dim2)
print("\nMultithreaded array muliplication:\n")
@btime decay4(x)

x = ones(dim1, dim2)
print("\nScale:\n")
@btime decay5(x)
```

`decay1` is the vectorized implementation, `decay2` is devectorized and `decay3` is multithreaded with 4 threads.
I am seeing the following timings.

```
Vectorized:
  2.291 ms (4 allocations: 112 bytes)

Devectorized:
  2.221 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

Multithreaded:
  1.963 ms (1 allocation: 32 bytes)

Multithreaded array muliplication:
  87.418 ms (2 allocations: 30.52 MiB)

Scale:
  2.042 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

The amount of speedup is clearly too low. What am I doing wrong? How can I do it better?

Comment: You might want to check out `BenchmarkTools.jl` to estimate the performance of your code.

Comment: BLAS level 1 operations (element-wise operations) don't really benefit all that much from multithreading since the cost of their op is offset by the cost of multithreading itself.

Comment: @Lost: What hardware are you testing on?  How are you compiling (full optimization options)?  Are you enabling AVX, if you're on x86 hardware?  You're probably bottlenecked on memory; a single core can come close to saturating DRAM on a dual or quad-core Intel desktop chip.  But on a big Xeon, single-threaded bandwidth is actually worse (in absolute GB/sec), so it takes more threads to saturate the higher total DRAM / L3 bandwidth: [Why is Skylake so much better than Broadwell-E for single-threaded memory throughput?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39260020).

Comment: There is also `scale!(A, b)` to scale an array `A` by a scalar `b` in-place.

Comment: Just to support the fact that this is hardware bound. On c5.9xlarge on AWS for 4 threads the relative timings are the following: vectorized: `2.556413`, devectorized: `2.358299` and multithreaded: `0.775768`.

Comment: @PeterCordes, apart from Bogumił's confirmation, I tested with added complexity in the called function and the timing remained the same as the element-wise multiplication. So, the memory bandwidth on my machine(Skylake i7-6700 with DDR4 memory) must be insufficient. I don't know if it qualifies, but if you post an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Yeah, your minor speedup from multithreaded looks reasonable for the memory bandwidth that a single thread would leave unused on i7-6700 on DDR4, I think, assuming SSE2 or AVX vectorization.  If anyone wants to post an answer with more details, feel free.  I probably won't have time to write anything up soon.